# How to solve error "git upload-pack: cannot find object"?

Tags: git, object

I have a bare repository I access over a SMB network. Quite often I suddenly get fatal error from clients trying to connect. Most of the time some push / pull / clone dance manage to solve it. This time, it's not even possible to clone the repos, I get :

```
fatal: git upload-pack: cannot find object 002d4400052e62e9047763229bef7ee69cf2c95f:
```

I don't understand what's wrong. This is even not a complicated repos : 30 commits at most, only linux client, some Mo in size...

How to solve this?
Why did it happen?
How to avoid this to happen again?

Comment: Are you able to clone that remote repository on the remote machine? I'd suspect corrupted repo due to some SMB disconnect.

Comment: It's a NAS, there is no real OS in the other side of the wire, just a big Hard drive with a web interface. But you are right, I suspect SMB for a lot of problems. We stoped to put draft project on it because syncdb didn't work on it. And it's not really reliable. It sucks, I probably should install a server but it's a pain as I'm in Africa and there is no broadband.

Comment: Ok, I tried to clone from a dir in the NAS, it didn't change anything. But rebooting alowed one client to pull and another one to clone. I just don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a reboot of the NAS hosting the repos, it started working again. Git can raise a lot of various errors when the hardware doesn't follow.

Morality : when you can't get any coherent debug, it may be because it's not a software problem.